# Angular text input submission fails to trigger console log

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The following code snippets are meant to create a text input form that displays a message to the console every time the user submits new text from it.

**AngularJS Snippet:**

```
myApp.controller("appCtrl", function ($scope) {

    var data = {
        text: ""
    };

    $scope.testSubmit = function () {
        console.log("Console Log");//I fail to see this message
    };

}
```

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<form ng-submit="testSubmit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.text"></input>
</form>
```

Unfortunately, I fail to ever see the console log message.  What am I missing?

Comment: That should work. Sure angularjs is running?

Comment: Yes -- because all of the other Angular code running is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. But are you forgetting the submit button? That's the only thing missing from your example. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/26/).

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="testSubmit()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.text"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle link proved that the code should work (even without the submit button).  The issue in my code was caused by an extra <form></form> wrapper.  When I deleted the extra <form>'s, the code worked as in the fiddle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an action on a link for example:`<a ng-click="testSubmit()">submit</a>`